# download percent in python progress bar exceeds 100

Tags: python, progress-bar

This is a part of a script to download files. The problem with it is the `downloaded_percent` sometimes exceeds 100.

```py
with open(outputname, 'wb') as DEST:
    chunksize = 8192
    downloaded = 0

    for chunk in SESSION.iter_content(chunk_size=chunksize):
        DEST.write(chunk)
        downloaded += chunksize

        downloaded_percent = (downloaded * 100) / file_size  ## <<< FIXME exceeds 100

        progress_info = {file_size: f'%{downloaded_percent:.2f}'}
        print(progress_info, end='\r')
```

This is what I've tried so far:

1. Using `if` statement before `write`, but it causes the exact opposite, i.e. `downloaded_percent` would never reach 100:

```py
if chunk:
    DEST.write(chunk)
    downloaded += chunksize

    downloaded_percent = (downloaded * 100) / file_size  ## <<< FIXME never reaches 100
```

2. Using `if` statement to set `downloaded_percent` to 100 if it is above that:

```py
DEST.write(chunk)
downloaded += chunksize

downloaded_percent = (downloaded * 100) / file_size  ## <<< FIXME exceeds 100
if downloaded_percent > 100:
    downloaded_percent = 100
```

This does the trick, but it does not seem efficient to check the amount in every iteration.

I was wondering if there are better ways to do so.

Comment: Did you tried to use 100. instead of 100 ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: downloaded_percent = (downloaded * 100.) / file_size

Comment: Oh, yes I just did, but still the same (e.g. it gives 100.14).

Comment: Could you provide values for "downloaded" and "file_size" for the case when you get "100.14" ?

Comment: Suppose `file_size = 9876`. The chunksize is `8192` or any other value. When the last chunksize is added to `downloaded`, it may exceed `file_size` (e.g. 9899) and this where I have to fix.

Comment: Seems that you are writing more data, according to the "chunksize"?

Comment: That's right. And I'm looking for a way to prevent that.

Comment: So you just have to check that last chunk and write required number of bytes, that's all. Percentage will be ok then.

Comment: Try this library: https://pypi.org/project/pretty-downloader/
Its exactly what you want

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
downloaded_percent = (downloaded / file_size) * 100
```

Assumming that `file_size` is always >= `downloaded`.

Comment: this formula also apply i.g to one 'poll' there were 50k persons enables to vote.. then guy 1 got 3400 votes and guy 2 got 40999 votes, what % got every guy from the 50k votes: guy1 = (3400/50000)*100 =  6.8% and guy2 = (40999 /50000)*100 =  81.99% great formula!!

Comment: @FreddyDaniel but this is no different from the one by Peter Stenger